# How to most efficiently detect file add/delete/rename changes of a directory in Python?

Tags: python

If I have a table representing paths and sizes of files/subdirectories inside directory A, how can I detect changes recursively in directory A so that I could update my table efficiently?

Answer (score 5):

I use [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog), which is a python library for just this kind of thing. If you want to know *how* they're doing it, you can dive into the source code of the project.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running on linux use [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify)